# How to get numbered internal wire name dump_module Yosys

Tags: yosys

I'm trying to debug how the printing in write_verilog works.

What is most curious to me that I'm unable to replicate the wire name for Yosys created intermediate wires.

If I take for example

```
void dump_sigchunk(std::ostream &f, const RTLIL::SigChunk &chunk, bool no_decimal = false)
{
    if (chunk.wire == NULL) {
        dump_const(f, chunk.data, chunk.width, chunk.offset, no_decimal);
    } else {
        if (chunk.width == chunk.wire->width && chunk.offset == 0) {
            f << stringf("%s", id(chunk.wire->name).c_str());
            log("Wire is\t%s\n", id(chunk.wire->name).c_str()); // attempt to print numbered wire name fails
        } ...
    }
}
```

Instead of giving me the numbered name, e.g. `_015_`, I only receive the internal name `$procmux$12_CMP`, even though the same id seems to appear as `_015_` in the verilog code.
Why is that so? For some reason, it only happens for this specific `procmux` family of wires, for all other intermediate wires, I get the correct numbered name.
Is that known behavior?

Comment: how are these wires being created? if they don't end up in `auto_name_map` then they also won't be renamed by that code

Comment: procmux is created via proc, whats strange to me is that the line before I call log (where sprintf is used) the internal process gets written as the number instead of $procmux$12_CMP